# matchFeatures WITH threshold?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

```
results = matchFeatures(matrix , matrix2);
```

this works very well for matching the exact features but by using features from images taken on separate occasions causes small differences.

how do i implement a tolerance into this so small differences will still count as a match.

any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In general, if you want to learn more about a function, try something like `help matchFeatures` or `doc matchFeatures`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/matchfeatures.html) for matchFeatures.  There are many options to tweak. The default matching 'Method' is 'NearestNeigborRatio', so the main knob there is the 'MaxRatio' parameter. Increasing its value will give you more matches.

Also, a lot depends on what interest point detector and what feature descriptor you are using.